# Create third person controller at runtime.but collision not occures

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I am trying to check collision between a rock(it's a cube scale: x=10, y=10, z=10) with my third person charactor(standard controller provided with Unity)controller that comes along with unity 3d. My cube have already assigned a rigid body. Third person controller have "charactor controller". The cube always move when the charactor controller collides with it. When iam trying to drag third person controller to the scene ,collision is possible...ie :it collide with wall ...but when i am trying to create a third person controller at runtime ,collision not occurs .....what is the reason for that.........how it possible?

Aim: When collide with rock, person stop its moving(dn't pass though th rock)[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use OnControllerColliderHit in order to get collisions from a character controller

https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/CharacterController.OnControllerColliderHit.html

Comment: @ bezzi : I have already drag this script to third person controller. But same prob...

Comment: Are you sure that there is a collider attached to it?

Answer (score 1):

Rigidbody is not enough to manage collision. You should attach a box collider to it and make it non-kinematic object in order to actually make a collision.

If the problem occurs at runtime, you are possibly missing some GetComponent for the character controller in the script.